# how to remove every space inside string by pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
df1 = spark.read.csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/BigData2021/Lecture23/datasets/cities.csv', header = True, inferSchema= True)
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

for name in df1.columns:
     df1 = df1.withColumn(name, F.trim(df1[name]))
     df1.show()
```

Here is my piece of code I try to trim every space in column header and also values but it does't work I need function to use every other df.

Comment: do you want to remove spaces in the start and the end of each column? smth looks wrong with your code. you loop on columns and print the result, but you don't save it. probably it's for debugging. anyway please add example of input and desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use use [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html?highlight=regexp_replace) to replace spaces in column values with empty string `""`.

You can use [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to remove spaces in column names.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("col1 with spaces  ", "col 2 with spaces", ), ], ("col 1", "col 2"))

"""
+------------------+-----------------+
|             col 1|            col 2|
+------------------+-----------------+
|col1 with spaces  |col 2 with spaces|
+------------------+-----------------+
"""
select_expr = [F.regexp_replace(F.col(c), "[\s]", "").alias(c.replace(" ", "")) for c in df.columns]

df.select(*select_expr).show()

"""
+--------------+--------------+
|          col1|          col2|
+--------------+--------------+
|col1withspaces|col2withspaces|
+--------------+--------------+
"""
```

Comment: thanks thats work great!! do U know how to change quotation mark by empty string ""?

Comment: where and how to add it on Ur code?

Comment: @sasaii the code already includes empty string using quotes, not sure we you are asking for.